# Query on System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory

Tags: c#, dns, active-directory, domaincontroller

I am using `Domain` object in `System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory` namespace. Whenever I query domain details using `Domain.GetCurrentDomain` or `Domain.GetDomain`, it establishes connection with domain controller. This connection can be seen with `netstat -ano|findstr 389` command.

Code:

```
Domain dom = Domain.GetCurrentDomain();
```

My question is, how to close the connection? The only way I can close the connection is to dispose the `Domain` object. Since I have cached the `Domain` object in my code I don't want dispose it. The problem it raises is, 'ESTABLISHED' state remains for some time later it changes to 'CLOSE_WAIT'.

```
netstat -ano | findstr 389

  TCP    10.241.93.168:51291    154.1.124.156:389      CLOSE_WAIT      8028
  TCP    10.241.93.168:51297    154.1.124.154:389      CLOSE_WAIT      8028
  TCP    10.241.93.168:51302    154.1.124.158:389      CLOSE_WAIT      8028
  TCP    10.241.93.168:51320    154.1.124.155:389      CLOSE_WAIT      8028
  TCP    10.241.93.168:51323    154.1.124.153:389      CLOSE_WAIT      8028
  TCP    10.241.93.168:51332    154.1.124.157:389      CLOSE_WAIT      8028
  TCP    10.241.93.168:53399    148.86.153.162:389     CLOSE_WAIT      8028
  TCP    10.241.93.168:53436    139.172.150.15:389     CLOSE_WAIT      8028
```

For security reason I need to eliminate this stale connection. Do let me know if you have any suggestions.

Thanks,Santhosh

Comment: You've already answered "how do you close the connection" - you do it by disposing of the object. If "I don't want to dispose it", that is a *conflict* in your requirements (close connection/avoid dispose). *You* need to decide which way you're going to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

I bet the that the `Domain` object keeps the connection open since you can perform operations on it.

If you just need to get some domain information you should probably read it and store it in a simple class and then dispose the `Domain`.